# wp_options not returning value for logged out users?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, plugin-options

I have saved my custom plugin settings inside wp_options table, but when I try to access them using "get_option" function it returns me undefined for logout users, but when I logged in it returns me the accurate value saved in the table, anyone can help me why is that happening or is it the default behavior?

this is how I am adding the option in wp_options table:

```
 add_option('token_limit' , $token_limit);
```

and this is how I am accessing it:

```
 $token_limit = get_option('token_limit');
```

Comment: There must be more to your code than the above, as what you are describing doesn't make sense in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect wp-includes/option.php is not being loaded in your environment. You must have the whole WordPress environment loaded to use get_option(). So e.g. per

```
include_once 'wp-load.php';
```